# Swift Как отследить ввод текста в WKWebView?

Tags: swift, email, webview, insert

Подскажите, плиз, в моем приложение используется WKWebView, который открывает определенный URL - на данной страничке есть поле для ввода e-mail, пользователь вводит почту и далее открывается следующая страничка, вопрос с помощью каких методов можно отследить почту(текст) который он ввел в определенном поле на страничке ? Например как на данном скриншоте.[image: скриншот]

Comment: Я так понимаю раньше можно было использовать метод "UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:" и отследить поле по ID, но теперь этот метод Deprecated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавлять скрипты которые будут встраиваться в страницу после ее загрузки. На JS написать метод отслеживания ввода и отправки сообщений в среду iOS по мере изменений значения в поле ввода. Как это сделать на JS не знаю, но могу подсказать как добавить скрипт:

```
webViewConf.userContentController = WKUserContentController()

let js = "..."
let script = WKUserScript(source: js, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
webViewConf.userContentController.addUserScript(script)

webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: webViewConf)
```

В `WKUserContentController` есть метод `add(_ scriptMessageHandler: WKScriptMessageHandler, name: String)` - думаю так можно получать сообщения из JS.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду думать

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял можно использовать этот метод: WebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('some text').value")